# Angular 2 / Typescript Scope

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm new in programming with typescript and angular. I write my first component and recognized a really strange behaviour. When I write something in the input form it propagates the characters between the browsers, when i have two windows open. It seems that each session shares only one component?

```
@Component({
selector: 'login',
providers: [AuthService],
template: `
    <div class="container my_container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 my_login">
                <h1 class="my_h1">Login </h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="admin.email"
                           name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="admin.password"
                           name="password">
                </div>
                <button (click)="login()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

`})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
admin: Admin;
returnUrl: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private authService: AuthService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    document.getElementById('myNavbar').style.display = "none";
    this.admin = new Admin("","");
    this.authService.logout();
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
}

login() {
    if (this.admin.email != "" && this.admin.password != "") {
        if (this.authService.login(this.admin.email, this.admin.password)) {
            document.getElementById('myNavbar').style.display = "block";
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        } else {
            alert("Wrong username or password!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Fill username and password")
    }
}}
```

Can someone please explain how to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks 
JerryP

Comment: What does this AuthService? If you are keeping stuff on localstorage and then opening a cloned window It's probably inheriting these data from the parent tab / window

Comment: It propagates between browsers? you mean Chrome and Firefox? Or between windows?
Did you try with incognito mode?
As a recommendation. Try to avoid 2 way data-binding: [(ngModel)], reactive forms are an awesome way to manage forms, you can subscribe to the form with an observable for the form or for any input that you need (with valueChanges). Avoid document.getElementById('myNavbar')... angular has other ways to manage that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for advice. It was BrowserSync in ghostMode which mirror all actions through the browsers. Setting "ghostMode": false in the bs-config.json solve this problem.